# What is the correct way of releasing nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, release, release-management

What is the correct way of releasing nodejs web application?

My current releasing script is doing following actions:

```
 Sync(function(){
    var tag = getTag.sync(); //1 - getting the tag to release   
    update.sync(null, tag);  //2 - update current project to choosen tag
    archive.sync();          //3 - archive current released project 
    stop.sync();             //4 - stop server
    del.sync();              //5 - delete currently released project
    copy.sync();             //6 - copy files from scm folder
    packAssets.sync();       //7 - minify javascript. css, less files
    start.sync();            //8 - start the application
 });
```

More detailed description - release is run in repository folder on same server (numbers as in comments):

1. Get tag by proposing last 10 ones and choosing the number or by writing tag name.
2. Update current repository to selected tag.
3. Archive application folder - copy it to archive folder with unique (data) name.
4. Stop the server by calling `forever stop pid` - from now Nginx will show maintenance mode page.
5. Delete current application folder
6. Copy files from repository folder to release folder (skip scm folder - in my case .hg)
7. Run minifying script for JavaScript, CSS and Less files.
8. Start the application by calling `forever start server.js` in release folder.

Functions (getTag, update, archive, stop, ... ) are declared above Sync call.

Is it correct?

Comment: i'm not sure which correct, i mean it looks like a live production server, where things aren't supposed to change, it should be kind of less risky than you are describing, keep things in `development` stage for more time and if ain't broken, then migrate in `production` mode and keep walking..

Comment: Yes this is live and I'm wondering how to release it correctly - I'm afraid this deleting step the most. I assume this tagged version is stable and want to release it.

Comment: have you considered using git in live production server? its easier and more manageable, than flat files, you get revert, discard changes and nothing is applied without permission.

Comment: Do you think git has something more to say here than mercurial? - I'm using mercurial a lot and thought it is almost same as git. Are you suggesting to just run the live application on repository folder?

Comment: no i'm saying to have a separate repository where live app exists, and another repository where you develop it,ex. openshift cloud platform lets you do this you clone the existing repository into the cloud and you pull/push from origin to live server. i don't think you will have any restrictions on using mercurial but git is more available on cloud .

Comment: Hmmm, I think I could do the same with mercurial branches (they are different than git one) and have e.g. LIVE branch and I will have it. In my example release I update to TAG which is made on LIVE branch, I will update the question. I will consider to run the application on repository folder then on LIVE branch :)

Answer (score 2):

Please consider using the following tools to release your JavaScript applications, they may help with SemVer versioning and make release process less error-prone:

- [Semantic release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release) - a release system that make it easy to perform actions before and after releasing a new version of your software
- [Bumped](https://github.com/bumped/bumped) - fully automated package publishing